# Converting dates, minutes and seconds to ISOdatetime format in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame which is similar to `dd` where

```
dd = data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2014-04-29", "2014-04-29","2014-04-29", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-29"), format ="%Y-%m-%d"), hh = 1:6, mm = seq(0, 50, 10))
```

I want to create new variables, call them `time1` and `time2`, where

- `time1` is time of day, irregardless of the date, e.g.: in row 1  `time1 = 01:00` [hh:mm] no entry for seconds
- `time2` is `date + time1`; e.g. for row 1 `time2 = 2014-04-29 : 01:00`

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Base R does not have a data type for time alone (only date+time). You can either store it as a string or set a sentinel date value to combine with the times. Optionally you can use some other library that may have such a data type.

Comment: The chron package has a `times` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R

```
dd$time1 <- format(strptime(paste0(dd$hh, ":", dd$mm), "%H:%M"), "%H:%M")
dd$time2 <- format(strptime(paste0(dd$date, ":", dd$hh, ":", dd$mm), "%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M"), "%Y-%m-%d : %H:%M")
```

Which will result in

```
dd$time1
## [1] "01:00" "02:10" "03:20" "04:30" "05:40" "06:50"
dd$time2
## [1] "2014-04-29 : 01:00" "2014-04-29 : 02:10" "2014-04-29 : 03:20" "2014-04-29 : 04:30"
##v[5] "2014-04-29 : 05:40" "2014-04-29 : 06:50"
```

They won't be `Date` type though (see @MrFlick comment)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
dd$time1 <- with(dd, hm(paste(hh, mm, sep=":")))
dd$time2 <- with(dd, ymd(dd$date) + time1)
```